# How to get Python 3 to register a random word from a external file as a variable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a computer science student at secondary school currently struggling with a certain aspect of my NEA, we are permitted to get help with the code. The aim of the NEA is to create a game which can choose a random song and artist from an external file and then get the user to guess which song it is. The issue I have run into is when I run the program the `random` aspect of the code (The Song name and artist chosen from the external file) does not seem to be registered by the `if` statement. I cannot think of a better way to explain my issue, but if you run the code I believe you will see the issue I'm having. I have taken out most of the excess code that is not part of the problem to make it easier to understand because like I said before I am still a novice at this. I have looked around for a while now and cannot seem to find an answer. Any sort of help would be very much appreciated.

```
username = 'Player1'
password = 'Password'

userInput = input("What is your username? (Case Sensitive)\n")

if userInput == username:
    userInput = input("What Is Your Password? (Case Sensitive)\n")
    if userInput == password:
        print(
            "Welcome! In this game you need to guess each songs name after being given its first letter and its artist. Good luck!"
        )
    else:
        print("That is the wrong password. Goodbye ;)")
        exit()
else:
    print("That is the wrong username. Goodbye ;)")
    exit()

startgame = 'Start' 'start'

userInput1 = input("Click Any Button And Click Enter To Begin Game:")

if userInput1 == startgame: 'Start'
print("Welcome To The Game")

import random

Song = [line.strip() for line in open("Songnames.txt")] #Currently in the external file I have removed all of the other songs apart from H______ By Ed Sherran.

print(random.choice(Song))

userguess = input("Whats Your Answer?\n")


if userguess == ("Happier") and (random.choice(Song)) == "H______ By Ed Sherran": #The program will continue to return 'Incorrect'.
    print("Nice One")

else:
    print ("Incorrect")
```

Any sort of help would be very much appreciated , I have looked for a while on this site and others for an answer however if it seems I have missed an obvious answer I do apologise.

Comment: Please format _and indent_ your code [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Like, for instance, your username/password check is not valid Python.

Comment: Thank you digitalarbeiter, I have amended the issues you pointed out.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works for me. Can you point out the specific error you get?

Comment: The code runs well on its own. However the issue is that I want it to print the "Nice One" message. However whenever the song is entered it comes back with "Incorrect". The beginning of the song code ' if userguess == ("Happier") ' runs fine. It returns "Nice One" as wanted. However when I added the ' and (random.choice(Song)) ==  ' aspect of it, the program returns Incorrect.

Comment: It works perfectly for me. As I said, I copied the same code and input `Happier` and the output is `Nice One`.

Comment: Can you show your Songnames.txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the code it seems to work. (My Songnames.txt contains one line, `H______ By Ed Sherran`.)

Is it possible that your `Songnames.txt` contains at least one empty line? If so, filtering the empty lines might fix the problem:

```
Song = [line.strip() for line in open("Songnames.txt") if line.strip()]
```

A few other suggestions for your code:

```
startgame = 'Start' 'start'
userInput1 = input("Click Any Button And Click Enter To Begin Game:")
if userInput1 == startgame: 'Start'
print("Welcome To The Game")
```

This doesn't make sense. Besides the misleading prompt about buttons and clicks, the `if userInput1 == startgame: 'Start'` doesn't do anything, not even print start. And the game starts regardless of what the user enters.

The actual game has a few issues as well, most importantly for when you actually have multiple songs is the fact that you choose a random song *twice*. Given enough songs, these will almost always be two *different* songs, so the `print` will be utterly misleading. Better choose *one* song and assign it to a variable:

```
import random
songs = [line.strip() for line in open("Songnames.txt") if line.strip()]
computer_choice = random.choice(songs)
print(computer_choice)
userguess = input("Whats Your Answer?\n")
if userguess.lower() == computer_choice.lower():
    print("Nice One")
else:
    print("Incorrect")
```

I took the liberty to make the comparison case insensitive by comparing the lowercase versions of the user guess and the computer's choice.

Comment: I have edited my code where you pointed out errors. Some I had been aware of but others I hadn't noticed. However I became confused when you mentioned choosing one song and assigning it to a variable. The code you posted above mostly makes sense to me however i cannot see where I would implement that into my original code.

Comment: You use `random.choice(Song)` twice in your code: in the `print()` statement and in the `if userguess == ("Happier")` condition. Before that `print`, set `computer_choice = random.choice(Song)` once and then change them to `print(computer_choice)` and `if ... and computer_choice=="H___`... respectively. (PS: May I politely suggest a more Metal song? A Rammstein song, perchance :-) )

Comment: Thank you very much! I have added everything you've said and taken out the same. It now works perfectly, iv even added R________ By Du Hast into my game to add a little metal. Again many thanks for the help!